# Updating values in some rows using values in other rows, based on some conditions on other columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a huge dataset in which I would like to update the values in some of the rows (i.e, that have `scenario=="D"`) with the value in another cell in the same column (i.e., column `outcome`) from another row (i.e, that has `scenario=="C"`), conditional on having the same values for other columns (i.e., `year` and `country`)

```
df <- data.frame(year=c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001"),
                 country=c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 scenario=c("C", "D", "C", "D"),
                 outcome=c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```

I would like to generate this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(year=c("2000", "2000", "2001", "2001"),
                 country=c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                 scenario=c("C", "D", "C", "D"),
                 outcome=c("1", "1", "3", "3"))
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replace` to conditionally replace the values for each group of `year` and `country`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(year, country) %>%
  mutate(outcome = replace(outcome, scenario == 'D', 
                           outcome[match('C', scenario)])) %>%
  ungroup

#   year  country scenario outcome
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>  
#1 2000  A       C        1      
#2 2000  A       D        1      
#3 2001  B       C        3      
#4 2001  B       D        3
```